# Enable/Disable ASP.NET Web Forms Required Validator for disabled inputs using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, validation, webforms

I'm using Web Forms Validators to prevent user from leave blank required inputs, but in my form some inputs may be disabled in some circumstance and need to disable validation for this textBox and dropdownlists.I try to using JQuery and remove some attributes to disable the validations, for instance:

**Disable**

```
$("#VDrpLeaveKind").css("visibility", "hidden").attr("data-val-enabled", false);
```

**Enable**

```
$("VDrpLeaveKind").removeAttr("data-val-enabled").css("visibility", "visible");
```

It's work when input disabled, but after clicking on the submit button, validation error message will appears again. There is Validation code:

```
<span data-val-controltovalidate="DrpLeaveKind" data-val-errormessage="error message" data-val-validationgroup="vacation" id="VDrpLeaveKind" data-val="true" data-val-evaluationfunction="RequiredFieldValidatorEvaluateIsValid" data-val-initialvalue="0" style="color:Red;font-size:Smaller;visibility:hidden;">error message</span>
```

I try some other ways like change *validationgroup*, or use *Causevalidation* but nothing. If further information needs, please inform me. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to enable/disable a validator clientside, you want to call ValidatorEnable and pass it the validator control and then a boolean to enable/disable it:

```
ValidatorEnable(requiredFieldValidator, false);
```

Reference [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479045.aspx).

Comment: It's Work for me, but the JavaScript Intellisense does not contain _ValidatorEnable_.

Comment: The best option is to disable the validations use
`ValidatorEnable(requiredFieldValidator, false);` and to enable use
`$("Input")[0].enabled = true;`